# How to handle AntiForgery token in Selenium webdriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, antiforgerytoken, chrome-web-driver

I'm getting an Antiforgery token issue while I am clicking an update button using selenium web driver automation in my web application. I'm using chrome browser. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Ask your developers to disable it in the test environment.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, When we check with the dev team they are asking us to handle it in the test script, Since I am new to automation, any help on this would be highly appriciatible

Comment: Where should the token be located (cookie, HTTP request header, ...)? What value supose the token to have (a constant string or some dynamic variable)?

Comment: The value to be located in cookie and the value is some dynamic string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anti forgery token and web testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989573/anti-forgery-token-and-web-testing)

Comment: No, it was not helpful.

Comment: 'some dynamic string' is not exact definition. It is possible to create cookies, but you still need to know what value should it contain.